# Querying the lookup relation object - getting null

Tags: apex, soql

I have a junction object `Asset_Tag__c` and with that junction I have a lookup relationship to `Device__c` when I try to query I always get the `null` for the device and I know there is data in it associated with the lookup.

here is my SOQL looks like:

```
Asset_Tag__c[] at = [SELECT id, Name, device__r.RecordType.Name from Asset_Tag__c];
```

I have tried something like this:

```
if(!at.isEmpty())
{
    system.debug(at[0].Device__r.RecordType.Name);
}
```

or like this:

```
 Device__c device = (Device__c)at.getSobject('Device__r');

 system.debug('device...: ' + device) //get null
```

Comment: Have you checked the sharing model on the object and Field Level Security for the lookup field?

Comment: If you `SELECT id, Name, Device__c......` what gets debugged for Device__c? Maybe the first record has NO device__c populated?

Comment: i have total of 10 records and all 10 records are showing null in the debug

Comment: @Bachovski: I have `Read, Create, Edit, Delete, View All, Modify All`

Comment: And the field level security on the `Device__c` lookup?

Comment: for the `Device__c` lookup is also the same

Comment: if(!at.isEmpty()){'Does it go inside this loop?'}

Comment: @AbuHamzah, "also the same"? If you're referring to the previous answer with Read, Create etc. that is not what I'm after. That's the object's access. You'll need to check the Field Level Security for the field `Device__c` on the `Asset_Tag__c` object : https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_fields_fls.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score -1):

try this query

Asset_Tag__c[] at = [SELECT id, Name, **device__c**, device__r.RecordType.Name from Asset_Tag__c];